# jQuery - How to inverse select?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="a-1">
<div class="a-2">
<div class="a-3">
<div class="a-1 a-2">
<div class="a-2 a-3">
<div class="a-1 a-3">
<div class="a-1 a-2 a-3">
```

I am looking to do something like this:

```
$('.a-1').show().siblings([all those that do not belong to a-1]).hide();
```

Is there anyway to achieve this? The `:not()` selector seems to be failing me because it's selecting the inverse of **each element** individually, resulting in a selection of all 7 DIVs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what your issue with `:not()` was but this should work fine:

```
$('.a-1').show().siblings(':not(.a-1)').hide();
```

Answer (score -1):

Works fine,with $('.a-1').show().siblings(':not(.a-3)').hide(); the a-1,a-2 and a-1 a-2 will become hidden since you are using the sibling() menthod, otherwise with $('.a-1').not('.a-3').hide(); only a-1 and a-1 a-2 will hide. for details visit :
http://mondalmrinmoy.blogspot.com/2018/07/jquery-selectors-few-advanced-notes.html

Comment: Please consider improving the formatting of your answer as well as correcting any spelling mistakes. At present it is very difficult to read. A guide on Stack Overflow's markdown can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)